# Terraform: Interate over map and access child values

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform variable defined like that:

```
variable "domains" {
  default = {
    instance01 = [
      "example.com",
      "www.example.com",
      "staging.example.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

Terraform version:
`Terraform v0.13.3`

How can I access the domain names in `instance01` and loop over the values?

How can I access the instance names and loop over the instance names?

Edit:

What I tried was creating a loop to iterate over each instance and over each domain name in the list associated to the instance:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "lb_listener_certs" {
  for_each        = var.domains
  listener_arn    = aws_lb_listener.front_end_https[each.key].arn
  certificate_arn = data.aws_acm_certificate.cert[each.value].arn
}
```

Error I get is:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 86, in resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "lb_listener_certs":
  86:   certificate_arn = data.aws_acm_certificate.cert[each.value].arn
    |----------------
    | data.aws_acm_certificate.cert is object with 3 attributes
    | each.value is tuple with 3 elements

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: string
required.
```

It should create for each key (e.g. instance01) and each child of the list a `aws_lb_listener_certificate` (e.g. `example.com`, `www.example.com`). But I cannot get it to interate over the items of the list assigned to `instance01`.

I basically want it to make a map like that:

```
instance01 => example.com
instance01 => www.example.com
instance01 => staging.example.com
```

I'd like to use this key value pair to create the `aws_lb_listener_certificate`.

Answer (score 0):

To get to a domain list use `var.domains.instance01`. This is the list of the domain.

Iterating over can mean multiple things in Terraform. If you want to transform the list, for example make it uppercase, use a for expression: `val = [for domain in var.domains.instance01: upper(domain)]`:

```
[
  "EXAMPLE.COM",
  "WWW.EXAMPLE.COM",
  "STAGING.EXAMPLE.COM",
]
```

If you want a resource for each of the domains for the instance, you can use a `for_each`:

```
resource "res" "r" {
  for_each = var.domains.instance01
  domain = each.key
}
```

(ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings)

To get the instance names, you can use the `key` function:

```
keys(var.domains)
```

```
[
  "instance01",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I got the solution:

```
variable "domains" {
  default = {
    instance01 = [
      "example.com",
      "www.example.com",
      "staging.example.com"
    ]
  }
}

locals {
  domain-association-list = flatten([
    for instance, domains in var.domains : [
      for domain in domains : {
        instance = instance
        domain = domain
      }
    ]
  ])

  domain-association-map = { for item in local.domain-association-list: 
     values(item)[0] => values(item)[1]
   }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "lb_listener_certs" {
  for_each        = local.domain-association-map
  listener_arn    = aws_lb_listener.front_end_https[each.value].arn
  certificate_arn = data.aws_acm_certificate.cert[each.key].arn
}
```